# What are those empty square braces in Symfony2 logs?

Tags: symfony

Starting with a default install of Symfony2, I logged an INFO-level message using this line in my controller:

```
$this->get('logger')->info('foo');
```

and this showed up in `app/logs/dev.log`:

```
[2012-07-06 10:56:19] app.INFO: foo [] []
```

What are those empty square braces?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From `Monolog\Formatter\LineFormatter`, it looks like the first `[]` is `%context%`, and the second is `%extra%`. Neither are populated by default. See [this useful doc](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/logging/monolog.html#adding-a-session-request-token) for how to 
replace the empty square brackets with a session token.

If you want to fill in `%context%`, here's an idea (don't use this for real, though):

```
$trace = debug_backtrace(); 
$record['context'] = $trace[3]['file'].':'.$trace[3]['line'];
```

See:

- https://groups.google.com/d/topic/symfony-devs/aycdKqEPUlk/discussion
- https://groups.google.com/d/topic/symfony-devs/7fxFTS0EK4g/discussion